# Gathering specific information from Database [SQLite]

Tags: android, sqlite

CODE:

```
private static final String CREATE_DETAILEDMEALS = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_DetailedMeals + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + mealsName + " TEXT unique," + categoryId + " INTEGER,"
        + desc + " TEXT," + size + " TEXT,"
        + price + " TEXT" + ")";

public void addDetailedMeals(String name, int catId, String d, String s, String p){
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
                values.put(mealsName, name);
                values.put(categoryId, catId);
                values.put(desc, d);
                values.put(size, s);
                values.put(price, p);
                getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_DetailedMeals, null, values);
            }

            public Cursor getMeals2(int id)
            {
                Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT Name, Description, Size, Price FROM " + TABLE_DetailedMeals + " WHERE " + categoryId + "=" + String.valueOf(id), null);
                return cursor;
            }

            // ID1 = MEALS
            public ArrayList<DetailedMeals> GetDetailedMeals(int ID1)
            {
                ArrayList<DetailedMeals> list = new ArrayList<DetailedMeals>();
                Cursor cursor =  getMeals2(ID1);
                int i = 0; // Iterator for 'do-while'. While it gets Categories names, it shall catch all the url's from array as well.
                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        DetailedMeals cat = new DetailedMeals();
                        cat.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mealsName))); //mealsName
                        cat.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mealsName)));
                        cat.setSize(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mealsName)));
                        cat.setPrice(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mealsName)));

                        switch (ID1) {
                            case 1:  cat.setImage(PIZZA_image_urls[i]);
                                break;
                            case 2:  cat.setImage(BEER_image_urls[i]);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        list.add(cat);
                        i++;
                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
                {
                    cursor.close();
                }
                return list;
            }
```

Adapter:

```
public class DifferentRowAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

FragmentActivity c;
ArrayList<DetailedMeals> MealsList;


private final int MEAL = 0, DETAIL = 1;

public DifferentRowAdapter(FragmentActivity c, ArrayList<DetailedMeals> MealsList) {
    this.c = c;
    this.MealsList = MealsList;
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case MEAL:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rec_item, parent, false);
            return new mViewHolder(view);
        case DETAIL:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.details_item, parent, false);
            return new dViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DetailedMeals object = MealsList.get(position);
    if (object != null) {
        switch (object.getmType()) {
            case MEAL:
                ((mViewHolder) holder).mNameTextView.setText(object.getName());
                Glide.with(c)
                        .load(MealsList.get(position).getImage())
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) // Saves the media item after all transformations to cache and
                        // Saves just the original data to cache.
                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .into(((mViewHolder) holder).img);
                break;
            case DETAIL:
                ((dViewHolder) holder).descTextView.setText(object.getDescription());
                ((dViewHolder) holder).sizeTextView.setText(object.getSize());
                ((dViewHolder) holder).priceTextView.setText(object.getPrice());
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (MealsList == null)
        return 0;
    return MealsList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (MealsList != null) {
        DetailedMeals object = MealsList.get(position);
        if (object != null) {
            return object.getmType();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public class dViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView descTextView;
    TextView sizeTextView;
    TextView priceTextView;

    detailsItemClickListener icl;

    public dViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        // Get references to desc, size, price
        descTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        sizeTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.size);
        priceTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(detailsItemClickListener icl)
    {
        this.icl = icl;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        this.icl.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
    }

}

public class mViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView mNameTextView;
    ImageView img;
    mealsItemClickListener icl;



    public mViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        // Get references to image and name.
        mNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(mealsItemClickListener icl)
    {
        this.icl = icl;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        this.icl.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
    }

}
}
```

DetailedMeals.class

```
public class DetailedMeals {

private String name;
private String image;
private String description;
private String size;
private String price;
private int id;
private int mType;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void setSize(String size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public int getmType() {
    return mType;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Right now, GetDetailedMeals(..) returns only details name (not name/desc/price/size) ect. and also, it tries to return it before I get recyclerview with only Meal names.

My goal here is: https://img.exs.lv/l/a/lat-deels/fragm_1.png

Comment: you have a list of `DiffRowAdapter`s, and try to put `DetailedMeals` in it. You can't *put a car in a list of dogs*

Comment: You should learn how to use Realm. Trust me. It is easy,and very quick to store data. No need to create read values with Cursors and declare table with that funny syntax that many gives compiler errors.

Comment: @Theo, Thanks for suggestion. Will look into it, but I'd love to solve this one tho.

Answer (score 0):

Change your DifferentRowAdapter extends to RecyclerView.Adapter because the viewholder you are using is within the DifferentRowAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

`list.add(cat);` in your code you are putting a **DetailedMeals** in a **DiffRowAdapter** list

So change the

```
public ArrayList<DifferentRowAdapter> GetDetailedMeals(int ID1)
```

to

```
public ArrayList<DetailedMeals> GetDetailedMeals(int ID1)
```

to have a same list and adapter.
then put result hear to know what happens.

**Update:**

after changing them you have just showing the name in your view so add more items like price or desc in mViewHolder:

```
public mViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    // Get references to image and name.
    mNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    // Add them hear
    mPriceTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    mDescTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);        
    img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: That worked, but please check my original post again - I made update on what's happening now. I guess my method for returning info from DB is wrong. I guess I select columns in some incorrect way.

Comment: to know that your cursor columns are correct or no, just show them with something like a toast or get logs....if the data was correct so then you can be sure for cursor healthy...at the next

Comment: mNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);

Comment: I'm 100% sure they're wrong, because I used "SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 ..." which (I think) is not working in this case and only returns first colomn - which is what I can see with my own eyes. Not sure how to Select multiple columns (specific) in the right way.

Comment: use this query `Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_DetailedMeals ,null, categoryId + " = "+ String.valueOf(id), null, null, null, null);'

Comment: About "Showing more info than just name" - but doesn't dViewHolder provide that it should say size,price ect. ?